# A faster, **indexed** analog of find and/or grep?

Tags: windows, shell, search, cygwin

I need a way to find files fast in a directory. That includes both file names and searching inside the file. Is there an easy way to do so under Windows 7 or Cygwin?

Edit: please read this carefully: *indexed* is the key. It needs to have the data indexed in some way. Please don't offer solutions that don't abide by this criterion.

Edit2: the solution must be something other than Windows' native indexing system. I have that. I want to improve upon it. Windows indexing proved unreliable and slow (the indexing process itself), with lots of false positives and false negatives, and I have to rebuild the index often.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/download/)

*A `Microsoft Windows` grep utility. Which searches within files for keywords. `AstroGrep` supports regular expressions, versatile printing options, stores most recently used paths and has a "context" feature which is very nice for looking at source code.*

Comment: tailorBird, Astrogrep does not allow indexing to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to expand on your question to get better help.

grep is a powerful tool (found in cygwin, you can no doubt find a windows flavour) that can descend down into subdirectories, so if you want to do something like: find all *.txt files that contain the word "chocolate", you can do

```
grep -Fwlr chocolate *.txt
```

Again, tell us what you want to do in greater detail.

Comment: does grep allow for indexing?

Comment: I am looking for a faster, indexed alternative to grep. It's in my subj line. (Now I've edited the body of the question, too).

Comment: a quick search turned up this: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-search-indexer-tips

Comment: Yes, Windows index is one way, and I am stuck with it now. Unfortunately, it's slow and prone to corruption; and has no command line interface to the best of my knowledge (not necessarily a show-stopper, but a nice feature). "Everything" is another tool I use. It's very efficient, but only searches for file names.